# data structure for string queries algorithm

Tags: automata

We have a finite set of words $D$, and denote $Pref(D)$ to be the set of all prefixes from words in $D$ and $l(D)=max_{w\in{}D}|w|$ is the length of the longest word from $D$.

**Problem statement**:

Given: $D$ subset $\{0,1,...,\sigma\}*$ $\;\;\leftarrow$ finite set of words $a-z$. We will have queries of the following type:

Input: $u,v \in Pref(D)$

Output: $min\big\{|\gamma| \big| u\gamma \in D \Leftrightarrow v\gamma \notin D\big\}$, where $\gamma\in\Sigma*$ is a word from the alphabet $a-z$.

How can we $describe$ algorithm such that solves the problem and has the following:

**Time for creating index (data structure)** $O(l(D)|Pref(D)|)$

**Memory** $O(|Pref(D)|)$

**Time for answering a query** $O(1)$

Comment: What's the context in which you encountered this task?   How do you know it can be solved with those running times?  What's the best data structure you can come up with?

Comment: There is no context. The problem is how it is. We only need do describe the algorithm, and tell how we will do it. The previous lesson was about suffix automata, so I guess maybe it will help, but I do not know haw and what it will give if we use it.

Comment: Did you see this in a textbook?  In a course?  Can you credit the source?